# Подключиться из Windows к базе mysql запущенной в докер контейнере в WSL2 Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, docker, wsl2

Есть Windows в которой запущена WSL2 c Ubuntu Linux. В Ubuntu запущен контейнер с MySQL.
Как (с какими параметрами) запустить контейнер с MySQL в WSL2, чтобы можно было подключиться к MySQL из хост системы Windows?

Comment: вы используете Docker Desktop или установили Docker напрямую в Ubuntu?

Comment: установил докер напрямую в Ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы установили `Docker` сами в `Ubuntu`, а не при помощи `Docker Desktop`, то получить доступ в сервисам (в вашем случае `MySql`) запущеным внутри можно, если запустить контейнер командой (с публикацией портов):

`docker run -p 3306:3306 <остальные параметры>`.

После этого вам нужно узнать `ip` вашей `Ubuntu`, например так:

`ip addr show eth0`.

Тогда в `MySql` можно будет подключиться по полученному адресу и порту `3306`, например: `172.26.123.72:3306`.